# Problemas con mi código

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy practicando mi código JavaScript, pero cuando intento ejecutarlo no realiza ninguna acción y tampoco muestra ningún error.
Fragmento de código HTML:

```
<div class="botones" id="cajaDeBotones">
<div class="boton" name="iz"></div>
<div class="boton" name="der"></div>
```

Fragmento de código:

```js
let boton = document.querySelectorAll(".boton"),
  contador = 1;

const botones = (e) => {
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case "iz":
      alert("hola");

      break;
    case "der":
      alert("adios");

      break;
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < boton.lenght; i++) {
  boton[i].addEvenetListener("click", botones);
}
```

Comment: `querySelector()` devuelve solo un elemento, deberías usas `querySelectorAll()` si se trata de 2 o más.

Comment: Disculpa la confusión, pero si fue con querySelectorAll()

Comment: Entonces coloca también el código HTML para poder tratar de identificar lo que está pasando y, **muy importante**, el código Javascript debe cargarse (o ejecutarse) después del HTML, lo más común es ponerlo al final, antes de `</body>`.

Comment: `addEvenetListener` eso esta mal escrito. `boton.lenght` Tambien eso.

Answer (score 4):

> Se actualizó esta publicación con información adicional sobre el atributo `name` en los elementos HTML `div`. La actualización la puede ubicar en la parte final.

### Posible error tipográfico

Básicamente, el código fuente está bien, excepto que, tienes que cambiar `addEvenetListener` por `addEventListener` y `lenght` por `length` , tal y como lo menciona `@Lobos` en uno de sus comentarios. Por lo tanto, es posible de que se trate de un error tipográfico.

Por ejemplo, si corremos el siguiente fragmento podemos observar que funciona una vez aplicada la corrección anterior:

```js
let boton = document.querySelectorAll(".boton"),
  contador = 1;

const botones = (e) => {
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case "iz":
      alert("hola");
      break;
    case "der":
      alert("adios");
      break;
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < boton.length; i++) {
  boton[i].addEventListener("click", botones, false);
}
```

```html
<button class="boton" name="iz">Botón izquierdo</button>
<button class="boton" name="der">Botón derecho</button>
```

Además, puedes refactorizar el código para que sea un poco más descriptivo. Se puede hacer utilizando el método `forEach()` o un bucle `for` .

Utilizando el método `forEach()` :

```js
let botones = document.querySelectorAll(".boton"),
  contador = 1;

const acciones = (e) => {
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case "iz":
      alert("hola");
      break;
    case "der":
      alert("adios");
      break;
  }
};

botones.forEach(boton => {
  boton.addEventListener("click", acciones, false);
});
```

```html
<button class="boton" name="iz">Botón izquierdo</button>
<button class="boton" name="der">Botón derecho</button>
```

Utilizando el bucle `for` :

```js
let botones = document.querySelectorAll(".boton"),
  contador = 1;

const acciones = (e) => {
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case "iz":
      alert("hola");
      break;
    case "der":
      alert("adios");
      break;
  }
};

for (let boton of botones) {
  boton.addEventListener("click", acciones, false);
}
```

```html
<button class="boton" name="iz">Botón izquierdo</button>
<button class="boton" name="der">Botón derecho</button>
```

### Actualización

Hay que tomar en cuenta que no es apropiado utilizar el atributo `name` en los elementos para los que no son destinados.

Extrayendo una parte de la [tabla de Referencia de atributos HTML de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos) nos encontramos con que el atributo `name` aplica a los elementos del formulario:

| Nombre del Atributo | Elementos | Descripción |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `name` | **button**, **form**, **fieldset**, **iframe**, **input**, **keygen**, **object**, **output**, **select**, **textarea**, **map**, **meta**, **param** | Nombre del elemento. Por ejemplo utilizado por el servidor para identificar los campos en el envio de formularios. |

Por lo tanto, si repetimos el experimento, pero esta vez, mostrando los resultados en la consola:

```js
let botones = document.querySelectorAll(".boton"),
  contador = 1;

const acciones = (e) => {
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case "iz":
      alert("hola");
      break;
    case "der":
      alert("adios");
      break;
  }

  console.log( "e.target.name", e.target.name)
};

for (let boton of botones) {
  boton.addEventListener("click", acciones, false);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dlunamontilla.github.io/estilos/style.css">

<div class="boton" name="iz">Botón izquierdo</div>
<div class="boton" name="der">Botón derecho</div>
```

Nos encontraremos con:

```
e.target.name = undefined
```

A menos, que utilicemos el método `getAtribute` para obtener el valor del atributo `name`, por ejemplo:

```js
let botones = document.querySelectorAll(".boton"),
  contador = 1;

const acciones = (e) => {
  switch (e.target.getAttribute("name")) {
    case "iz":
      alert("hola");
      break;
    case "der":
      alert("adios");
      break;
  }

  console.log( "e.target.getAttribute(\"name\")", e.target.getAttribute("name") );
};

for (let boton of botones) {
  boton.addEventListener("click", acciones, false);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dlunamontilla.github.io/estilos/style.css">

<div class="boton" name="iz">Botón izquierdo</div>
<div class="boton" name="der">Botón derecho</div>
```

Obviamente, funcionaría, pero, no sería apropiado. Para ese caso, es preferible utilizar `data-name` en lugar de `name`:

```html
<div class="boton" data-name="iz">Botón izquierdo</div>
<div class="boton" data-name="der">Botón derecho</div>
```

Para poder acceder más tarde con `elemento.dataset.name`, por ejemplo:

```js
let botones = document.querySelectorAll(".boton"),
  contador = 1;

const acciones = (e) => {
  switch (e.target.dataset.name) {
    case "iz":
      alert("hola");
      break;
    case "der":
      alert("adios");
      break;
  }

  console.log( "e.target.dataset.name", e.target.dataset.name );
};

for (let boton of botones) {
  boton.addEventListener("click", acciones, false);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dlunamontilla.github.io/estilos/style.css">

<div class="boton" data-name="iz">Botón izquierdo</div>
<div class="boton" data-name="der">Botón derecho</div>
```

Referencias:

- [Referencia de Atributos HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos)
- [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, acabo de publicar mi código HTML pueden decirme ¿por que esta mal?

Comment: En realidad, no está mal. Son por los errores tipográficos que había en tu código. De hecho, está explicado en esta publicación y los comentarios. Lo puedes ubicar en el primer párrafo de esta publicación la razón. Allí se explica. Solo observa detalladamente, las palabras resaltaas.

Comment: Presione los botones ejecutar para que puedas observar el ejemplo y observa el código HTML.

Comment: Por otra parte, observé que el código HTML que has colocado hará que tu código JavaScript no funcione porque se marcará como `undefined` el atributo `name` en un `div`, mientras que en un botón eso no ocurrirá.

Comment: Los presione con el código que copie de aquí y no funcionaba, hasta que copie el HTML de esta pagina

Comment: ¡Oh! muchas gracias amigo